# Что делают символы 7 (BEL) и 48 (0) в этом коде?

Tags: excel, vba

Нашел в Интернете такую функцию перевода чисел из 10 ной системы счисления в любую на vba:

```
Function Number_Convert(ByVal Value As Long, Baza As Byte) As String
Dim M As Byte
Do
M = Value Mod Baza + 48
If M > 57 Then M = M + 7
Value = Value \ Baza
Number_Convert = Chr$(M) & Number_Convert
Loop While Value > 0
End Function
```

Что делает в строке

```
If M > 57 Then M = M + 7
```

символ BEL?

И зачем прибавлять к остатку ноль?

```
 M = Value Mod Baza + 48
```

Помогите разобраться в работе функции, спасибо.

Comment: *символ BEL* Это просто семёрка. *48* Переводит 0 в '0'.

Comment: Откройте charmap и посмотрите расстояние между `9` и `A`

Comment: 57 — это код символа 9, а 57+1+7 — это код символа A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Function Number_Convert(ByVal Value As Long, Baza As Byte) As String
    Dim M As Byte

    Do
        ' Находим остаток от деления. '
        ' Это будет индекс символа в алфавите (символы [0-9] и [A-Z]). '
        ' Как видно из таблицы, алфавит имеет смещение и начинается с индекса 48 '
        ' Прибавляем 48 для выравнивания индексов '
        M = Value Mod Baza + 48
        ' Если индекс получился больше числа 57, значит это не цифра, а буква. '
        ' А так как буквы начинаются с индекса 65, то прибавляем 7, '
        ' чтобы обойти разрыв между цифрой 9 и буквой A в алфавите (таблице) '
        If M > 57 Then M = M + 7
        Value = Value \ Baza
        ' Каждый новый остаток записываем в начало строки '
        Number_Convert = Chr$(M) & Number_Convert
   Loop While Value > 0
End Function
```